# How to pass parameter in current url to an html template in Django 3

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have:

Movie Model

```
    class Movie(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
       synopsis = models.TextField()
       author = models.ForeignKey(
           get_user_model(),
           on_delete=models.CASCADE,
       )
       def __str__(self):
           return self.title

       def get_absolute_url(self):
           return reverse('movie_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Discussion Model

```
class Discussion(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   body = models.TextField()
   author = models.ForeignKey(
       get_user_model(),
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   )
   date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
   movie = models.ForeignKey(
       Movie,
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
       related_name='discussion',
   )

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title

   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('discussion_detail', args=[str(self.movie.id), str(self.id)])
```

DiscussionListView

```
class DiscussionListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
   model = Discussion
   template_name = 'discussion_list.html'
   login_url = 'login'
```

And I also have discussion_list.html

Here is what I want:

1. I’m in the url `/article/1/discussion/`. The integer `1` is a `movie_pk` because the url is defined as `/article/<int:movie_pk>/discussion/` which in this case refer to the priority key of a Movie Model, for example StarWars I. This is a page of list of discussion titles related to this movie. (This has already been achieved)
2. There is a button “New” where, if i click on it, I will be directed to /article/1/discussion/new. There, I can create a new discussion. (The feature I want to add)

However:
In discussion_list.html, we require the url tag `{% url discussion_new %}` to have a parameter since `discussion_new` is defined as  `/article/<int:movie_pk>/discussion/new`

Thus:
How to pass the `movie_pk` from the current url, then to DiscussionListView, then to the template discussion_list.html?

Answer (score 0):

In detail view's template, you can send the `object.id` as parameter of url:

```
#template
{% url "discussion_new" movie_pk=object.pk %}
```

If you are in a List View template then probably you have a loop to go through all object_list. There you can implement like this:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
   {% url "discussion_new" movie_pk=object.pk %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
              {% url discussion_new %}
```

to

```
            {% url "discussion_new"  pk=movie_pk%}
```

And in list

```
        {% for m in movie_list %}
            {% url "discussion_new" movie_pk=m.pk %}
        {% endfor %}
```